# Embed CSS/HTML button into email from scratch

Tags: html, css, email, button, hyperlink

Wanting to put button-operated hotlinks to wherever into my emails I attacked the problem using advice from various sources on the web.

Having ZERO previous HTML experience (let alone CSS) the final solution is probably a bit of a dog's dinner but it works!

My only problem is that I think my method of specifying the target URL is a bit suspect and I wonder if it is stable and suitable for all platforms.

The other problem (possibly related) is that the company server is unhappy about the security of the email.

p.s. used Komodo as my HTML editor - menus are in strange places but other than that a nice piece of (free) kit.

Code below:

```
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
.myButton {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #3e7327;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #3e7327;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #3e7327;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #77b55a), color-stop(1, #72b352));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #77b55a 5%, #72b352 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #77b55a 5%, #72b352 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #77b55a 5%, #72b352 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #77b55a 5%, #72b352 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #77b55a 5%, #72b352 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#77b55a', endColorstr='#72b352',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#77b55a;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #4b8f29;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:6px 12px;
    margin:4px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #5b8a3c;
}
.myButton:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #72b352), color-stop(1, #77b55a));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #72b352 5%, #77b55a 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #72b352 5%, #77b55a 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #72b352 5%, #77b55a 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #72b352 5%, #77b55a 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #72b352 5%, #77b55a 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#72b352', endColorstr='#77b55a',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#72b352;
}
.myButton:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
</style>

<a href=https://www.anysite\ class="myButton">BUTTON LEGEND</a>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not an actual question and more of a broad "optimize/fix my code" request.

Comment: Start with the basic stuff: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

Comment: Specifically want to know if my use of href=(URL) is stable ...